# Deleting more Specific Nodes on a Linked List?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I created a **linked-list** program using the following source code,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

struct HeadNode
{
    int count;
    Node *headPtr;
};

class LinkedList
{
    public:
            LinkedList();
            ~LinkedList();

            void addToHead( int );
            bool removeFromHead();

//          bool addToTail ( int );
//          bool removeFromTail();

            void addNode ( int );
            bool deleteNode ( int );
            void deleteAllNodes();

            bool isEmpty();
            int getNoOfNodes();

            void displayAllNodes();

    private:
        int dataCmp ( int, int );
        void displayNode ( Node* );

        HeadNode head;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head.count = 0;
    head.headPtr = NULL;
    return;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    deleteAllNodes();
    return;
}

void LinkedList::addToHead ( int newData )
{
    Node *pNew = new Node;
    pNew -> data = newData;
    pNew -> next = head.headPtr;
    head.headPtr = pNew;
    head.count++;
}

bool LinkedList::removeFromHead()
{
    bool exit;
    Node *temp;

    if ( head.headPtr )
    {
        temp = head.headPtr;
        head.headPtr = head.headPtr -> next;
        delete temp;
        head.count--;
        exit = true;        // returns true if it's successful
    }
    else
        exit = false;       // returns false if it's not successful
    return exit;
}

/*
bool LinkedList::addToTail( int )
{

}
bool Linked::removeFromTail();
{

}
*/

void LinkedList::addNode ( int newData )
{
    Node *pNew = new Node,
         *pPre = NULL,
         *pCur = head.headPtr;
    pNew -> data = newData;

    while ( pCur && dataCmp( pNew -> data, pCur -> data ) >= 0 )
        {
            pPre = pCur;
            pCur = pCur -> next;
        }

    if ( pPre )
    {
        pNew -> next = pPre -> next;
        pPre -> next = pNew;
        head.count++;
    }
    else
    {
        pNew -> next = head.headPtr;
        head.headPtr = pNew;
        head.count++;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::deleteNode( int data )
{
    bool exit;
    Node *pPre = NULL,
         *pCur = head.headPtr;

    while ( pCur && dataCmp( pCur -> data, data ) < 0 )
    {
        pPre = pCur;
        pCur = pCur -> next;
    }

    if ( pCur && dataCmp( pCur -> data, data ) == 0 )
    {
        if ( pPre )
        {
            pPre -> next = pCur -> next;
            delete pCur;
            head.count--;
            exit = true; // return true if successful
        }
        else
        {
            head.headPtr = pCur -> next;
            delete pCur;
            head.count--;
            exit = true; // return true if successful
        }
    }
    else
        exit = false; // return false if unsuccessful

    return exit;
}

void LinkedList::deleteAllNodes()
{
    Node *temp;

    while ( head.headPtr )
    {
        temp = head.headPtr;
        head.headPtr = head.headPtr -> next;
        delete temp;
        head.count--;
    }

    return;
}

bool LinkedList::isEmpty()
{
    return head.count == 0;
}


int LinkedList::getNoOfNodes()
{
    return head.count;
}

void LinkedList::displayAllNodes()
{
    Node *pCur = head.headPtr;
    int nodeCount = 1;

    while ( pCur )
    {
        cout << "Node " << nodeCount << ": ";
        displayNode( pCur );
        cout << endl;

        nodeCount++;
        pCur = pCur -> next;
    }

    return;
}

int LinkedList::dataCmp( int value0, int value1 )
{
    int exit = 0;

    if ( value0 < value1 )
        exit = -1;
    else if ( value0 > value1 )
        exit = 1;

    return exit;
}

void LinkedList::displayNode( Node *node )
{
    cout << node -> data;
    return;
}

void printMenu()
{
    cout << "1. Add to head" << endl;
    cout << "2. Remove from head" << endl;
    cout << "3. Add node " << endl;
    cout << "4. Delete node" << endl;
    cout << "5. Delete all nodes" << endl;
    cout << "6. Is the list empty?" << endl;
    cout << "7. Get number of nodes" << endl;
    cout << "8. Display all nodes" << endl;
    cout << "9. Quit" << endl;
}

int getChoice()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "Select choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( 200, '\n' );
    return choice;
}

int getData()
{
    int data;

    cout << "Enter data: ";
    cin >> data;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore( 200, '\n' );

    return data;
}

void processChoice( int choice, LinkedList& list )
{
    int data;
    bool opStatus;

    switch ( choice )
    {
        case 1: data = getData();
            list.addToHead( data );
            break;
        case 2: if ( list.removeFromHead() )
            {
                cout << "Removed node from head" << endl;
            }
            else
                cerr << "List is empty" << endl;
            break;
        case 3: data = getData();
            list.addNode( data );
            cout << "Node " << data
                 << " added";
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 4: if ( !list.isEmpty() )
            {
                data = getData();
                if ( list.deleteNode( data ) )
                {
                    cout << "Node " << data
                         << " deleted";
                    cout << endl;
                }
                else
                    cerr << "Node not found" << endl;
            }
            else
                cerr << "List is empty" << endl;
            break;
        case 5: list.deleteAllNodes();
            cout << "All nodes deleted" << endl;
            break;
        case 6: cout << ( list.isEmpty() ? 
                      "List is empty" : "List is not empty" );
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 7: cout << "No. of nodes: "
                 << list.getNoOfNodes();
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 8: list.displayAllNodes();
            break;
        default: cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printMenu();
        choice = getChoice();

        if ( choice != 9 )
            processChoice( choice, list );

    } while ( choice != 9 );



    return 0;
}
```

I feel the "Delete Node" option is too ambiguous and would like to split it into two functions, delete by node number *(EX: Delete Node Number 0)* and delete by Node's number *(EX: Delete node with 5667)*. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: So you want to delete a node based on the value of `data` in it?  And if so would you want to delete all nodes with that value?

Comment: I think you should always considering deleting node number. Delete node with specific data is ambiguous. In general, linked lists allow repetitions.

Comment: You should use `std::list` as it has already been tested; which saves you a lot of time.

Comment: @FKunecke Whatever matches the credentials would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node based on its value, you would have to step through your list, and check to see if each node's value matches the one you're trying to eliminate from your list.

I believe that is the only way you can do this.